# Powershell GPO Login Script checking AD resource group membership

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

The system I have to work with uses AD resource group membership to manage most of the permissions for users and computers. I have been asked to improve the current logon script as it currently contains some VB ADSISEARCHER calls. I started trying to do this purely in powershell but have hit a number of hurdles.

- Target machines do not have the Active Directory Module installed
- The users logging into the system have a restricted user accounts
- The resource groups are nested so the script needs to handle this

I have tried a couple of approaches firstly the pure Powershell Cmdlet method of Get-ADGroup or Get-ADPricipalGroupMembership but these Cmdlet's require the Active Directory Module. Then I tried the .net approach with System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry although this is a step away from a pure PowerShell solution at least it isn't as Legacy as the VB route. However when I try to build the object it also appears to be missing the name space.

First Attempt:

```
function Get-UserResourceMembership
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # Username or Groupname to Discover Group Membership
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                   Position=0)]
        $User
    )

    Begin
    {
        $Groups = @(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User)
    }
    Process
    {
        foreach($ADGroup in $Groups)
            {
                if($ADGroup.ObjectClass -eq "Group")
                {
                    Get-UserResourceMembership $ADGroup
                }

                $GrpMembership = @($ADGroup)
            }
    }
    End
    {
     return ,$GrpMembership
    }
}
```

Second Attempt:

```
# $rootGroup is passed in from earlier in the script

$groupname = $rootGroup.'Group Name'
$filter = ("(&(objectCategory=Group)(name=$($groupname)))")
$searcher.Filter = $filter
$searcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$searchResults = $searcher.FindAll().GetDirectoryEntry().memberOf |
% { (New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+$_)) } |
Sort-Object Children | select @{name="Group Name";expression={$_.Name}}

foreach($resource in $searchResults)
    {
        if($resource.'Group Name' -match "<Groupname>")
        {
            $printResource += $resource
        }
    }
```

Does anyone in the community have any suggestions how to pull group membership [nested] from Active Directory from a standard users login script??? Any idea's much appreciated....

PS I can't change the way the system is designed (above my pay grade).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for ...

> • Target machines do not have the Active Directory Module installed
>
> • The users logging into the system have a restricted user accounts
>
> • The resource groups are nested so the script needs to handle this

- Does not matter, they do not need to be installed on a client to use
  them. You can use PSRemoting to proxy those using 'Implicit
  Remoting'. The cmdlets are only available in the remote session.
- Does not matter, as every user has read access, by default to ADDS
  in Windows.
- You can get to those using the cmdlets you are using and
  there are even pre-built scripts in the Microsoft PowershellGallery.com
  for this as well.

As for …

> I have tried a couple of approaches firstly the pure Powershell Cmdlet
>   method of Get-ADGroup or Get-ADPricipalGroupMembership but these
>   Cmdlet's require the Active Directory Module.

As noted above, this can be addressed as described below:

[PowerShell Implicit Remoting: Never Install a Module Again](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-implicit-remoting-never-install-module-again)

[Remote Session](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/import-powershell-module-remote-machine)

```
# create a session then import a module via the session, for example:
$adsess = New-PSSession -ComputerName savdaldc01
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory -PSSession $adsess
Get-Module
Get-ADUser -Filter *
Remove-Module ActiveDirectory

# It's also possible to prefix modules loaded from remote servers to differentiate from local modules, e.g.

Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory -PSSession $adsess -Prefix OnDC
Get-OnDCADUser -Filter * #I don't have regular Get-ADUser anymore
Remove-Module ActiveDirectory
Remove-PSSession $adsess
```

As for ...

> Does anyone in the community have any suggestions how to pull group
>   membership [nested]

[Get nested group membership - function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-nested-group-15f725f2)

> This function will recursively enumerate members of a given group
>   along with nesting level and parent group information. If there is a
>   circular membership, it will be displayed in Comment column.It accepts
>   input from pipeline and works well with get-adgroup. Download:
>   Get-ADNestedGroupMembers.ps1

As well as just doing this...

> We can get group members by using the Active Directory powershell
>   cmlet Get-ADGroupMember. The Get-ADGroupMember cmdlet provides the
>   option to get all the nested group members by passing the parameter
>   -Recursive. This powershell script also handles circular membership (infinite loop) problem.

```
Function Get-ADNestedGroupMembers 
{
  [cmdletbinding()]

  param 
  ( 
      [String] $Group 
  )            
  Import-Module ActiveDirectory
  ($Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Recursive)
}

Get-ADNestedGroupMembers "Domain Admins" | Select Name,DistinguishedName
```

or this way.

```
function Get-NestedGroupMember
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Identity
    )

    process
    {
        Import-Module ActiveDirectory
        $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity
        $userdn = $user.DistinguishedName
        $strFilter = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$userdn)"
        Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter $strFilter -ResultPageSize 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: Had thought about PSRemoting but this is not available at all of our sites and we need to stick to a single script. I have however managed to sort out the issue with the .net method which was a permissions issue. PSRemoting is the way to go in future version

Answer (score 0):

All of the methods below list all groups including **nested** groups.

The example below would execute a `gpresult` command in the user's context. The `gpresult` outputs to an XML file within the user's local profile, which they should have full access to already. Then the XML file is read and traversed through each node until you reach the node containing the groups. The group list contains local and domain groups and is outputted directly to the console. This can easily be stored in a variable or output to a file. If you only want domain groups, that could easily be filtered from here with a Regex. It requires that the client machines are running at least Windows Vista SP1 or later.

```
gpresult /USER "$env:userdomain\$env:username" /X "$env:userprofile\rsop.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content "$env:userprofile\rsop.xml")
$xml.Rsop.UserResults.SecurityGroup.Name."#text" # Displays the groups
Remove-Item "$env:userprofile\rsop.xml" # Removes the XML file
```

You could also use a potentially use Regex matching to find the group list:

```
$out = gpresult /R /USER $env:username
$GroupsUnfiltered = (($out | out-string) -split "-{10,}")[-1]
$Groups = ($GroupsUnfiltered.trim() -replace "(?m)^\s+","") -split "(?m)\r?\n"
$Groups
```

The following can also work if your group list always begins with a predictable group like Domain Users in this example:

```
$out = gpresult /R /USER $env:username
$GroupList = $out.where({$_ -match "domain users"},'SkipUntil').trim()
$GroupList
```

This code assumes that the users and machines are joined to the same domain or are at least joined to trusted domains. The second code snippet assumes every user is in the Domain Users group and the machines are natively PowerShell v4 or higher.

Comment: Hi @AdminOfThings... Thank you for the code, can't beat a good hack  however my brief was to remove the legacy cmd\VB code from the current script so I don't think this would be approved upstairs... love it though, thanks again.

Comment: @RootUser, I added another code block at the top of my post that is a more reliable way of using RSOP data to find groups.